# I am not able to solve java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet exception

Tags: java

In the programs given below, I have implemented actionlistener on "a" whereby when a click event occurs on button "H" new window asking coordinates should appear but I am getting

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet exception

I would appreciate any suggestions to it. I have included two classes.

```
// class:TextEditor.java

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextEditor extends JFrame {
static int fn=0;
private JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20,120);
//TextEditor frm = new TextEditor(10,10);

    private JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    private String currentFile = "Untitled";
    private boolean changed = false;
        private JButton a = new JButton("H");
        private JButton b = new JButton("HE");
        private JButton c = new JButton("O");

public TextEditor() {
                setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        area.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN,12));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                add(a);// add the button to the JFrame
                add(b); 
                add(c);
        JMenuBar JMB = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(JMB);
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMB.add(file); JMB.add(edit);

                a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                     CircleComponent a1 = new CircleComponent();
                a1.a2();
                selectionButtonPressed();
                    } 

                    private void selectionButtonPressed() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }
                } );
                file.add(New);
                file.add(Open);
                file.add(Save);
                file.add(SaveAs);
        file.add(Quit);
                file.addSeparator();

        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            file.getItem(i).setIcon(null);

        edit.add(Cut);
                edit.add(Copy);
                edit.add(Paste);

        edit.getItem(0).setText("Cut out");
        edit.getItem(1).setText("Copy");
        edit.getItem(2).setText("Paste");

JToolBar tool = new JToolBar();
        add(tool,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tool.add(New);
                tool.add(Open);tool.add(Save);
        tool.addSeparator();

        JButton cut = tool.add(Cut), cop = tool.add(Copy),pas = tool.add(Paste);

        cut.setText(null); cut.setIcon(new ImageIcon("cut.gif"));
        cop.setText(null); cop.setIcon(new ImageIcon("copy.gif"));
        pas.setText(null); pas.setIcon(new ImageIcon("paste.gif"));

        //Save.setEnabled(false);
        //SaveAs.setEnabled(false);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        area.addKeyListener(k1);
        setTitle(currentFile);
        setVisible(true);
    }
private KeyListener k1 = new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            changed = true;
            Save.setEnabled(true);
            SaveAs.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
Action New = new AbstractAction("New", new ImageIcon("new.gif")) {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveOld();
            currentFile = "Untitled";
                        setTitle(currentFile);
                        changed = false;
                        area.setText(null);
                }
    };
Action Open = new AbstractAction("Open", new ImageIcon("open.gif")) {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveOld();
            if(dialog.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                readInFile(dialog.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }
            SaveAs.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
Action Save = new AbstractAction("Save", new ImageIcon("save.gif")) {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!currentFile.equals("Untitled"))
                saveFile(currentFile);
            else
                saveFileAs();
        }
    };
Action SaveAs = new AbstractAction("Save as...") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveFileAs();
        }
    };
Action Quit = new AbstractAction("Quit") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveOld();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };
        private TextEditor(int i, int i0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
  ActionMap m = area.getActionMap();
    Action Cut = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
    Action Copy = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
    Action Paste = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);

private void saveFileAs() {
        if(dialog.showSaveDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            saveFile(dialog.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }
private void saveOld() {
        if(changed) {
            if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Would you like to save "+ currentFile +" ?","Save",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)== JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                saveFile(currentFile);
        }
    }
private void readInFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            FileReader r = new FileReader(fileName);
            area.read(r,null);
            r.close();
            currentFile = fileName;
            setTitle(currentFile);
            changed = false;
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Editor can't find the file called "+fileName);
        }
    }
private void saveFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            FileWriter w = new FileWriter(fileName);
            area.write(w);
            w.close();
            currentFile = fileName;
            setTitle(currentFile);
            changed = false;
            Save.setEnabled(false);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
        }
    }
public  static void main(String[] arg) {
        new TextEditor();
    }

    private void setsize(int i, int i0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void a() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void a2() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}

//circlecomponent

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CircleComponent extends JPanel
{
       Ellipse2D.Double circle;

       public CircleComponent(int radius)
       {
           circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, radius, radius);
           setOpaque(false);
       }

    CircleComponent() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

       public Dimension getPreferredSize()
       {
            Rectangle bounds = circle.getBounds();
           return new Dimension(bounds.width, bounds.height);
       }

       public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
       {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
           g2.setColor( getForeground() );
           g2.fill(circle);

       }
/*
       public int getWidth(int aWidth)
       {
            width = aWidth;
            return width;
       }
*/

    public void  a2()
    {
            //  Create a panel using a null layout so we can add components at random positions
            final JPanel center = new JPanel();
            center.setLayout(null);

              JButton button = new JButton("Draw");
              button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
              {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                 {
                     String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("X Coordinate", "Enter an x coordinate");
                       try{
                     int xCoord = Integer.parseInt(x);
                     String y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Y Coordinate", "Enter a y coordinate");
                     int yCoord = Integer.parseInt(y);
                     String width = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Radius", "Enter the length of the radius");
                     int radius = Integer.parseInt(width);
                     CircleComponent component = new CircleComponent(radius);
                     component.setLocation(xCoord,yCoord);
                     component.setSize(component.getPreferredSize());
                     center.add(component);
                     center.repaint();
                     }catch(NumberFormatException ex){  

        System.err.println("Ilegal input");
                 }
                 }
              });

              JFrame frame = new JFrame();
              frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
              frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
              frame.setSize(500, 500);
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void addActionListener() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    void addActionListener(ActionListener actionListener) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

 /*   CircleComponent() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    CircleComponent() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    CircleComponent() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }*/
}
```

Comment: What did you expect? On the action performed method you are calling selectionButtonPressed which throws UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: You are throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` from everywhere... The first one throwed is the one in your `CircleComponent` empty constructor when you click on your H button

Comment: I didn't even see the other ones you need to implement them manually.

Comment: thanks i removed all exception calls even but the error still prevails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should learn debugging; but in that case you do not have to debug it.

When I run your code and Click H Button, it gives

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.   at
>   CircleComponent.**(CircleComponent.java:24)**   at
>   TextEditor$7.actionPerformed(**TextEditor.java:58**)

So we see that the exception occurs on line 24 in CircleComponent (You are throwing it, I do not know why)

```
23  CircleComponent() {
24      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
25  }
```

Tips: Developer Comment on line 24 says; do not use it, choose Tools | Templates. So you need to not call new CircleComponent on line 58 in TextEditor.java again from Exception Trace or contact with the CircleComponent Developer ;)

Updated version of your code(without UnsupportedOperation exceptions);

```
// class:TextEditor.java

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;

public class TextEditor extends JFrame {
    static int fn = 0;
    private JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20, 120);
    // TextEditor frm = new TextEditor(10,10);

    private JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    private String currentFile = "Untitled";
    private boolean changed = false;
    private JButton a = new JButton("H");
    private JButton b = new JButton("HE");
    private JButton c = new JButton("O");

    public TextEditor() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        area.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(a);// add the button to the JFrame
        add(b);
        add(c);
        JMenuBar JMB = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(JMB);
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMB.add(file);
        JMB.add(edit);

        a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CircleComponent a1 = new CircleComponent();
                a1.a2();
                selectionButtonPressed();
            }

            private void selectionButtonPressed() {
            }
        });
        file.add(New);
        file.add(Open);
        file.add(Save);
        file.add(SaveAs);
        file.add(Quit);
        file.addSeparator();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            file.getItem(i).setIcon(null);

        edit.add(Cut);
        edit.add(Copy);
        edit.add(Paste);

        edit.getItem(0).setText("Cut out");
        edit.getItem(1).setText("Copy");
        edit.getItem(2).setText("Paste");

        JToolBar tool = new JToolBar();
        add(tool, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tool.add(New);
        tool.add(Open);
        tool.add(Save);
        tool.addSeparator();

        JButton cut = tool.add(Cut), cop = tool.add(Copy), pas = tool.add(Paste);

        cut.setText(null);
        cut.setIcon(new ImageIcon("cut.gif"));
        cop.setText(null);
        cop.setIcon(new ImageIcon("copy.gif"));
        pas.setText(null);
        pas.setIcon(new ImageIcon("paste.gif"));

        // Save.setEnabled(false);
        // SaveAs.setEnabled(false);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        area.addKeyListener(k1);
        setTitle(currentFile);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private KeyListener k1 = new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            changed = true;
            Save.setEnabled(true);
            SaveAs.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
    Action New = new AbstractAction("New", new ImageIcon("new.gif")) {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveOld();
            currentFile = "Untitled";
            setTitle(currentFile);
            changed = false;
            area.setText(null);
        }
    };
    Action Open = new AbstractAction("Open", new ImageIcon("open.gif")) {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveOld();
            if (dialog.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                readInFile(dialog.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }
            SaveAs.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
    Action Save = new AbstractAction("Save", new ImageIcon("save.gif")) {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!currentFile.equals("Untitled"))
                saveFile(currentFile);
            else
                saveFileAs();
        }
    };
    Action SaveAs = new AbstractAction("Save as...") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveFileAs();
        }
    };
    Action Quit = new AbstractAction("Quit") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveOld();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };

    private TextEditor(int i, int i0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    ActionMap m = area.getActionMap();
    Action Cut = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
    Action Copy = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
    Action Paste = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);

    private void saveFileAs() {
        if (dialog.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            saveFile(dialog.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private void saveOld() {
        if (changed) {
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Would you like to save " + currentFile + " ?", "Save", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                saveFile(currentFile);
        }
    }

    private void readInFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            FileReader r = new FileReader(fileName);
            area.read(r, null);
            r.close();
            currentFile = fileName;
            setTitle(currentFile);
            changed = false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Editor can't find the file called " + fileName);
        }
    }

    private void saveFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            FileWriter w = new FileWriter(fileName);
            area.write(w);
            w.close();
            currentFile = fileName;
            setTitle(currentFile);
            changed = false;
            Save.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new TextEditor();
    }

    private void setsize(int i, int i0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void a() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void a2() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CircleComponent extends JPanel {
    Ellipse2D.Double circle;

    public CircleComponent(int radius) {
        circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, radius, radius);
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    CircleComponent() {
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Rectangle bounds = circle.getBounds();
        return new Dimension(bounds.width, bounds.height);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(getForeground());
        g2.fill(circle);

    }

    /*
     * public int getWidth(int aWidth) { width = aWidth; return width; }
     */

    public void a2() {
        // Create a panel using a null layout so we can add components at random positions
        final JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setLayout(null);

        JButton button = new JButton("Draw");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("X Coordinate", "Enter an x coordinate");
                try {
                    int xCoord = Integer.parseInt(x);
                    String y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Y Coordinate", "Enter a y coordinate");
                    int yCoord = Integer.parseInt(y);
                    String width = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Radius", "Enter the length of the radius");
                    int radius = Integer.parseInt(width);
                    CircleComponent component = new CircleComponent(radius);
                    component.setLocation(xCoord, yCoord);
                    component.setSize(component.getPreferredSize());
                    center.add(component);
                    center.repaint();
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

                    System.err.println("Ilegal input");
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void addActionListener() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    void addActionListener(ActionListener actionListener) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    /*
     * CircleComponent() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose
     * Tools | Templates. }
     * 
     * CircleComponent() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose
     * Tools | Templates. }
     * 
     * CircleComponent() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose
     * Tools | Templates. }
     */
}
```

Comment: really appreciate your response.I am working in netbeans and the following code gives me error  CircleComponent a1 = new CircleComponent(); it asks me to create constructor of class CircleComponent i don't know why it is asks to create a constructor.

Comment: @yash Did you try remove `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.")` from CircleComponent.java and also remove 'throw new UnsupportedOperationException' lines from TextEditor.java

Comment: really appreciate your response.I am working in netbeans and the following code gives me error  CircleComponent a1 = new CircleComponent(); it asks me to create constructor of class CircleComponent i don't know why it is asks to create a constructor.

Comment: yes i did removed it but i asks me to create a constructor of CircleComponent

Comment: @yash do not remove constructor,  remove only  `throw new UnsupportedOperationException` line

Comment: @yash have a look updated answer with whole code to fix exception problem.

Comment: i am getting error on the same line to create a constructor to throw exception

Comment: Did you try whole code(TextEditor&CircleComponent) which I gave end of the answer?

Comment: one last question this program is for text editor can i convert it into an editor to save images

Comment: @yash You're welcome, accept answers instead comment if it worked ;) it is possible but I think you need to work much more to do that.

Comment: yeah really appreciated your help ill post the question later on